# React state based on mouse/keyboard press/release

Tags: html, reactjs

i'm creating a custom button with React.

The appearance based on the press/release of the mouse/keyboard.
Sometimes it cannot be done by css using `:active` pseudo, so i need the javascript solution.

So i created a state that listen the `onMouseDown/Up` & `onKeyDown/Up`.

The problem is, if the user **click the button** then **drag the mouse out of the button** then **release the mouse**,
i miss the **onMouseUp** event thus causing the activeState locked up forever.

Do you have a solution for the equivalent of the `:active` & `:not(:active)` pair in javascript way?

note:
watching event `window.addEventListener('mouseup',...)` is still not satisfying me. When the mouse click hold & move out from the browser's window, i still missing the mouseup event.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to do css as much as you can for this type of scenario, otherwise you would be updating the state of the component unnecessarily, can you explain why this cannot be done via CSS in more detail?

Comment: there are press & release animation on the button (not just css transition, a complex animation). I need a .release class during the kb/mouse release and then the .release will be removed after the animation end. the .release also removed immediately on the press event.

Comment: note, using :not(:active) causing the release animation always run on the first startup, so i really need the .release class for doing the job. The pseudo :release is not exist, so i created a custom class.

Comment: have you tried with `document[mouseout]`?

Comment: `window.addEventListener('mouseup',...)` doesn't miss the event when out of browser window for me. When combined with `window.addEventListener('blur',...)` to catch alt+tab etc. I think it could work pretty well

Comment: yeah you're right, the mouseup fires after go back to browser window.